# Comments form - why should I ask for email?

Tags: validation, email, comments, spam

I am developing a CMS for my personal blog. Currently, I am interested in making my own comments form and after reviewing several example practices on the internet I've seen that almost every comment section asks a person to supply their email address (which is a required field).

My first assumption would be that it is needed for comment validation - a valid email address seems less like something that belongs to a spammer, but why not user verification codes near the submit button to avoid spam?

Could anyone explain why would I want both my users and anonymous commenters to supply their email address in order to be able to post a comment?

Comment: You could either get bot spammers, but as you say, a verification code could stop that. Valid users could post bad language etc if only a verification code is required, but they are less likely if they need to supply their email address too - that said they could also supply a bogus email address.  So, if you are going to force email, then you might as well get them to set up an account.

Comment: Foul language could be either filtered using regular expressions or simply moderated by me. So I guess the email part is mostly needed for purely ethical and subscription purposes - the former being a sense of connection between your online behavior and your web-identity (email address). I'm aware that people are less likely to abuse the freedom of speech when they provide their own email address, but as you said, it could easily be a non-existent one anyway. I guess requiring an email address would be pretty pointless on my website then.

Comment: yes, unless they subscribe with only the address.  I have a few blogs I comment on, with a limited profile - email and screen name.  You have the ability to personalise further, e.g. Track my comments, keyword topics etc.  As for RegEx for the foul language, this is very hard to implement.

Comment: Another possible reason: The email address is a direct link to gravatar.com. Avatar pictures provide a more visual and personal experience for all participants. (However, I myself am no friend of requiered email fields.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, in addition to verification (which is pretty pointless without answerback authentication), it's so that contributors can receive notifications of posts to the same thread on the assumption that they are interested in the on-going 'conversation'

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about "answerback authentication"?

Comment: You sign on -> I send you mail -> you reply -> I know you're real -> I let you have access .... you see it all the time on bulletin boards etc. If that process isn't used, it's useless for authentication since I could give you any e-mail address I like as long as it's authentic. I would appear to be OK, and then I could spam you to death ...In the case of a comments section on a blog then most often providing the e-mail is optional, and is an information thing.

Comment: If you want to be fairly sure the contributor is human, just use a capcha image - if you want to share with them, ask them for their e-mail but don't make it compulsory.